# Converting custom array type to character varying array in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have created custom type

```
 CREATE TYPE address AS (city VARCHAR(90), street VARCHAR(90));
```

I need to convert this type to character `varying[]`. I am getting error as

> cannot cast type customtype_address to character varying[]

Comment: why did i get -1 reputation here can i knw

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the cast function:

```
[local] @ test #= CREATE TYPE address AS (city VARCHAR(90), street VARCHAR(90));
CREATE TYPE

[local] @ test #=  -- CREATE the cast function
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION address2varchar_array (address address)
  RETURNS VARCHAR[] AS $$
    SELECT ARRAY[address.city, address.street]
  $$ LANGUAGE SQL;

[local] @ test #= -- CREATE the cast
  CREATE CAST (address AS VARCHAR[]) WITH FUNCTION address2varchar_array(address);
```

---

Then:

```
[local] @ test #= CREATE TEMP TABLE t (a address);
CREATE TABLE

[local] @ test #= INSERT INTO t VALUES (('paris', 'something'));
INSERT 0 1

[local] @ test #= SELECT a::VARCHAR[] FROM t;
┌───────────────────┐
│         a         │
├───────────────────┤
│ {paris,something} │
└───────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 CREATE TYPE address AS (city VARCHAR(90), street VARCHAR(90));
 CREATE  TABLE contact1 (adr address);
 INSERT INTO contact1 VALUES (('cityone', 'addressone'));
```

create a function like below to convert `address` type to `varchar[]`

```
create or replace function addresstovarchar(val address) returns 
varchar[] as
$$
select string_to_array(trim(trim(val::text,'('),')'),',')::varchar[] 
$$language sql
```

usage :

```
select addresstovarchar(adr) from contact1
```